# Uninstalling LDAP on Fedora

Tags: fedora, ldap

I'm attempting to maintain a legacy collection of Fedora VMs, all configured to a old LDAP server. However, it's very touchy, and whenever the VM running the LDAP server is slow or unresponsive for any reason, everyone gets locked out of the entire system, since no one can login.

As I no longer have the manpower to manage such a complicated setup, I want to completely remove LDAP as the single point of failure, and simply use SSH keys to login to the VMs, so if one VM is down it won't disable all the others. As I'm the only person who ever logs into these systems anyways, having LDAP is overkill.

What's the easiest way do do this? I tried the obvious `yum remove openldap` but that attempted to uninstall nearly all packages, including yum. I currently can't login to any of them, so I have to boot each VM in single user mode and start its network interface.

Comment: try `yum remove *openldap*`

Comment: when it wanted to remove everything... you didn't say yes, right?

Comment: @Networker, attempting to remove `openldap` removes 312 other packages, including `yum`...